# Invoke create handle from a backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

i'm working to populate a listview with a loop in a backgroundworker and the background worker was run initially from a 2nd active form. To picture it i've open a form1 then open another form (form2) that was use to run a form1.backgroundworker runasync.

Form1 with the backgroundworker -  at the back

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker wk = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        DataTable dtdt = new DataTable();
        dtdt = qr.history();

        for (int i = 0; i < dtdt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            DataRow dr = dtdt.Rows[i];
            ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["custnum"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["custname"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ratecable"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["rateinternet"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["rateext"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["status"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["classname"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SVCstadd"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SVCctadd"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["svctelno"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bilstadd"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bilctadd"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billtel"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billtel2"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["fax"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["zoneno"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["zoneName"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bookno"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["seqno"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Balance"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance1"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance2"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance3"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billamnt"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["maxdate"].ToString().Trim());


            qr.lsi = listitem;
           //error  {"Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."}
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { additemtoLV(listitem); }));


        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
             }

    private delegate void additemtoLVdelegat(ListViewItem ls);



    public void additemtoLV(ListViewItem ls)
    {
        if (IsHandleCreated)
        {
             BeginInvoke(new additemtoLVdelegat(additemtoLV), ls);
              }
        else
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(ls);
        }
    }
```

Form2 -use to call form1.backgroundworker - in front of form1 - note form1 is already open

```
   private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        form1 f1 = new form1 ();
        f1.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        this.Close();



    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling sleep in the background worker?  Why are you making a new background worker inside the background worker?  Why are you always replacing the `qr.lsi` object in every loop?  The only code you should have in your DoWork method is `dtdt = qr.history();` since that is the only apparent long running operation in your code.  Everything else should happen on the GUI thread.

Comment: qr.lsi is only a listviewitem constructor for back up data
dtdt = qr.history() -  is the dowork sql query. dtdt is a datatable - it hold the data which i query then i loop it and place it on a listviewitem and add the item on the listview via backgroundworker. the main problem im having trouble is that the listview got a row count but the UI listview doesnt display anything

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, form1 is not opened. You have to call Form.Show and wait for Form.Load.

```
form1 f1 = new form1 ();
f1.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I suggest that you start background worker in Form1_Load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And show Form1 to allow Form1_Load be fired.

```
private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1 f1 = new form1();
    f1.Show();
}
```

Comment: no.. form1 is already open. form1 is actually a waiting form... when i open form1 no process must be done. then i open form2 and close form2 it will call form1.backgroundworker to run the process.

Comment: Why do you "new form1()" in Close_Click if form1 exists?

Comment: yes...good point.. and ive been asking that to myself. Can you enlighten me on how can i call an open form controls without using the new form1()

Comment: Simplest way is to create a method or property in Form2 letting Form1 pass itself to Form2 before calling Form2's Show or ShowDialog.

Comment: interesting, can u give me a sample one. I'm still new to this threading thing. Thank you.

Comment: Before i forgot there are 2 different button that opens form1 and form2 like from the MDI form Button1 opens Form1 and button 2 opens form 2